# Where should I using OpenCL data types?

Tags: types, opencl

I have a question: where should I using OpenCL data types? For what are us? Which are covered they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some types are defined in the OpenCL C programming language, like `int`, `float4`, etc.

The corresponding types are defined in the host API with the `cl_` prefix, like `cl_int`, `cl_float4`, etc. These types are used in the OpenCL API functions, and should be used to pass kernel arguments and compute the size of buffers for example.

Comment: So when I proces some buffer of unsigned char then on host site must I defined this buffer as cl_uchar then copy it to device, process it and back to the host to buffer which is defined as cl_uchar again?

Comment: Yes. The OpenCL standard fixes the size of these types, and it may differ from the sizes used by the C compiler (afaik there is no fixed size for char or int in C).

Comment: And what about size_t, there is no compliant of OpenCL type. When I use size_t on 64-bit host it has size 8, but on the NVIDIA GPU has size 4. So I use on device instead unsigned long. It's good decision or it can cause problems?

Comment: Kernel arguments can't be `size_t`, see OpenCL reference 6.8.k