# What's the OpenCL equivalent of the C++ type std::vector::size_type?

Tags: c++, opencl

This topic was touched upon in [Where should I using OpenCL data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963800/where-should-i-using-opencl-data-types) but it didn't answer my questions.

(1) What should the binding opencl type and the kernel opencl type be for C++ type std::vector::size_type?

(2) How do I convert std::vector::size_type to the binding type you've mentioned in your answer to (1) before setting it as a host ptr into clCreateBuffer()?

The reason I need the above is because I'm trying to pass the size of a vector into my kernel.

Comment: There's no such thing as "std::vector::size_t". There's only `std::vector::size_type`, which is typically the same as `std::size_t`.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected this in my question.

Comment: @KerreSB: Indeed, `std::allocator<T>::size_type` is required to be `std::size_t`. So it would be a bit perplexing for `vector<T>::size_type` to be different, different allocators may vary.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends. `cl_uint`/`uint` and `cl_ulong`/`ulong` are possible alternatives. The former is sufficient when the size of your vector is at most 2³² - 1. If and only if you exceed that limit, you should think about using `cl_ulong`/`ulong`. Chances are that you will break some other limits before it comes to that, e.g. the maximum allowed buffer size (`CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE`) or the address space (`CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS`) of the device. So my advice would be to stick to `cl_uint`/`uint` unless there is a very good reason to use `cl_ulong`/`ulong`.
2. `static_cast<cl_uint>(v.size())` or even `boost::numeric_cast<cl_uint>(v.size())` (which throws an exception if the value cannot fit into a `cl_uint`).